# Azure VMSS scale-in policy not allowing me to set a cool down period of more than 60 mins for my scale-in rules

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I have a very specific issue while configuring a SCALE-IN rule for my azure VMSS instances. I am not able to set a cool down period of more than 60 mins which i want for my application as sometimes we experience traffic after an hour but don't want to switch off the instance unless it is more than 90 mins and still no traffic is experienced.